# Sudakov double logarithm

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics

I have calculated a few NLO corrections in QED and in the final result the Sudakov double logarithms have always canceled. So I thought that they have no physical meaning. On the other hand I have seen a papers where people talk a lot about these logs, they even resum them and define Sudakov form-factors. So my question are: Do the Sudakov logs have a physical meaning and why? Can we measure the double logs in any observable?